# Unable to locate package bitcoin

Tags: command-line, apt, bitcoin

I have added the official `ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin` to my software sources and have done `sudo apt-get update`, but every time I try `sudo apt-get install bitcoin` this error pops up.:

```
E: Unable to locate package bitcoin
```

How can I fix this?